# Can I set a pdfstartview that is compatible with Google Chrome?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, viewers

I would like to have the default setting for my PDF be to fit the page to the window of the PDF viewer.

My entire tex file is

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview={Fit}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Test}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When I open the PDF output of this in `atril` document viewer, it fits the slide to the window, but when I open the PDF file in Google Chrome, it presents the slide with its absolute dimensions by default.

Is there a setting for `hyperref` that is compatible with Google Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

So...... Instead of *actually* changing the display setting, I found a work-a-round that is practical but **not** elegant. Basically, I am magnifying the pages to be an extremely large absolute size. Then when Google Chrome (or another viewer) opens it, the viewer zooms out until it is able to fit one page width (by default).

Adding the line below does the necessary magnification (although 10000 is probably overkill).

```
\geometry{mag=10000,truedemin}
```